# Understanding ffmpeg -i input.mp4 out.mp4

Tags: ffmpeg

What actually `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 out.mp4` is doing, it just change codec to some default? Can this command change number of frames and duration of video as side effect?

Comment: Is this really a question about _software development_?

Comment: (also, wrt asking about side effects, it's important to distinguish whether you're inquiring about intended or actual behavior; once presence of bugs or behavior in presence of malformed inputs comes into scope, the question is a lot broader; if you're asking if unintended changes to duration are possible, that's different from asking if changes to duration are able to happen during the course of normal and correct behavior; there are a lot of files with mp4 extensions in the world, and some of them are going to be out-of-spec and prone to differences in handling between consumers).

Comment: Anyhow -- context matters. If the intent behind the question is "why would code ever do this?" (in the context of trying to understand some preexisting code), that makes it clearer what you're trying to do (though maybe still not a good SO question -- getting into the head of someone who wrote the code you're trying to read is not exactly a narrow and specific ask). Whereas if your real question is "why is this command shortening my video's playback?", that's a very different question than the first one (and also arguably requires a [mre], and may be off-topic even with one).

Comment: (going back to the "why would anyone do this?" point -- in general I wouldn't recommend it as it means a generation of quality loss; but if you're worried about security vulnerabilities trying to attack folks playing the videos via intentionally malformed streams; or you want to reduce content encoded at way higher-than-default quality levels to be smaller/saner; or you want to change "mp4" files that are actually using oddball codecs to be encoded in a more consistent way, then that command could _potentially_ make sense).